# Error in Symbol Selector Sample for ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I am stuck at running this [ArcGIS Engine Sample code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000037z000000.htm), when I get:

> [COM EXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED BY THE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990189/activex-common-dialog-control-error-in-c-sharp)

I'm looking for any working example of Symbol Selector.

I'm working on XP SP3, ArcGIS 10.1 and ArcGIS Engine 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also get an error when attempting to click the context menu item in the sample:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'MapControlAppPropertyPage.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {F9043C85-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040112.
The thread '' (0x4d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

It sounds from the comment on your SO question that this just comes down to the sample relying on a really old 3rd party library ([PropertyPages.dll](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/nfc/article.php/c8545/Extensible-OLE-Property-Pages-in-NET.htm)) that has since been broken by 1 or more security patches.

If someone with C++ experience took the time they could probably recompile the DLL from the provided source code to make the sample work, but it's probably unnecessary. You can [create property pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_property_pages/0001000004s7000000/) without it, so I'm not sure why it's used in this case.

You could also just look at the source code and the designer to get an idea of how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the test, i was wondering if the bug happens just in my case. Concerning properety pages i'm steel newbie i will use them for the 1st time, i have browsed the code, but i don't know how i could get ride of this dll and resolve the problem.

Comment: There's another sample here that uses property pages without it: [Layer property page and property sheet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000v1000000)

Comment: Oh that sample is for Desktop, I'm not sure if it can be adapted to Engine (you'd probably have to remove the Framework, ArcMapUI and CartoUI references and strip out functionality relying on them).